# Formal description of algorithmic subtyping/cumulativity

Tags: subtyping, cumulativity, reference-request

Are there any references (papers, documentation, etc.) for how proof assistants with subtyping due to cumulativity actually implement algorithmic subtyping? Coq, for instance, has subtyping, but the [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/cic.html#subtyping-rules)'s description doesn't seem to be complete (e.g. you wouldn't be able to derive `(λ_: Prop. Set) True ≤ (λ_: Prop. Type) True` from what it lists alone), and refers to transitivity, which as a rule wouldn't be algorithmic anyway, I don't think. The only other proof assistant I know with cumulativity is Arend, but their [docs](https://arend-lang.github.io/documentation/language-reference/expressions/universes) don't detail rules either. (Are there more?)

I've seen formal descriptions of subtyping and their derivation rules in papers like [pCuIC](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01615123v2/) and the ones it cites, but they all seem to include some form of a transitivity rule (either `A ≼ B ≼ C` or `A ≈ B ≼ C ≈ D`). I'm particularly interested in an algorithmic presentation that's known to be sound wrt these usual presentations of subtyping with a transitivity rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For more recent references for, you can look at what [MetaCoq](https://github.com/MetaCoq/metacoq) does, either the code (there’s now a proof of correctness and completeness of an actual checker wrt. a declarative spec) or the papers (the ones around are starting to be quite behind the formalization, hopefully there will be a new one soon).

Comment: Neat! I'm guessing you're referring to this: https://metacoq.github.io/html/MetaCoq.PCUIC.PCUICTyping.html#lab96;
I can't find this declarative spec you're referring to though, which definition is that?

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have been more precise: the active development branch is currently `coq.8.14`. The declarative spec is [here](https://github.com/MetaCoq/metacoq/blob/c0b680c5ca5bc25a35d1e936923f81b9d9f31f0c/pcuic/theories/PCUICCumulativitySpec.v#L29), it is proven equivalent to the one you’ve found (now named CumulAlgo) [here](https://github.com/MetaCoq/metacoq/blob/coq-8.14/pcuic/theories/PCUICConversion.v), and the certified conversion checker is [here](https://github.com/MetaCoq/metacoq/blob/coq-8.14/safechecker/theories/PCUICSafeConversion.v).

Answer (score 8):

See [Universe Polymorphism in Coq](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-08970-6_32) (ITP 2014) by Matthieu Sozeau and Nicolas Tabareau ([freely available draft](https://sozeau.gitlabpages.inria.fr/www/research/publications/drafts/univpoly.pdf)) which explains in detail what Coq is doing.